# Using readmore.js plugin with a dynamically created div tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

readmore.js works beautifully when I want to collapse an entire div. I need to figure out how to use the readmore plugin with dynamically created divs, so I can collapse just the parts of my table that need it.

I am returning an unknown number of rows from the database and putting them in a table. The fields are date, contact name and comment. The comment field can be quite long so I'd like to use .readmore() on each comment.

What I'm currently doing is dynamically creating a div for the comment field. The idea is to use that div id with .readmore()

My loop looks like so:

```
// NoteTable is html file's div that will display all the returned data
// jquery append method is used to add a table and children rows:
$('#NoteTable').append('<table></table>'); 
var table = $('#NoteTable').children();
table.append('<tr><td colspan="2" class="sec-hd2">Discharge Planning Notes</td></tr>');

// Loop thru the returned data in the json object:
for (var i = 0; i < jsonNote.DATAREC.LIST.length; i++) {

  // Add a row for date info:
  table.append('<tr><td><b>Date:</b></td><td>' + jsonNote.DATAREC.LIST[i].COMMENT_DT + '</td></tr>');

  // Add a row for contact name info:
  table.append('<tr><td><b>Personnel:</b></td><td>' + jsonNote.DATAREC.LIST[i].COMMENT_PRSNL + '</td></tr>');

  // use the loop# to create a unique ID for a new div tag:
  var tempID = 'comment' + i
  //alert (tempID)

  // Add a row for the comments with a div tag around the comment string:
  table.append('<tr><td colspan="2"><div id="' + tempID + '">' + jsonNote.DATAREC.LIST[i].COMMENT + '</div><br />&nbsp;</td></tr>');

  // Use the readmore plugin on this new div:
  //table.append('$(#' + tempID + ').readmore()');
  // QUESTIONS/PROBLEMS WITH PREVIOUS LINE OF CODE:
  //  1) I'm not sure if I need to append it to the table like I do everything else
  //     (I don't get errors using tempID.readmore without the table.append but it doesn't work either
  //  2) I'm not sure how to do the quote marks/pound sign/dollar sign when I build this string

}
```

No matter how I've configured that last line of code, I don't have "read more" on any of the comments. I'm not sure how what the syntax should be. Appreciate any ideas. I'm open to completely reworking this if that would be better.

More info: [*readmore*](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Readmore.js is a jQuery plugin, it can take a selector that returns an array of elements. So, what I would recommend is adding a class, rather than an id, to your dynamically generated div, and then use that class to init Readmore.js:

```
// Add a row for the comments with a div tag around the comment string:
table.append('<tr><td colspan="2"><div class="long-text">' + jsonNote.DATAREC.LIST[i].COMMENT + '</div><br />&nbsp;</td></tr>');
```

Then, outside of your loop, after you've built the table and appended it to the DOM:

```
$('.long-text').readmore();
```

That should do it.

Comment: I tried this solution on dynamically created divs which were added to the DOM with html(), but it didn't work. Same initialization worked for statically created div with the same class name though.